# C# Локализация поиск строки

Tags: c#, локализация

У меня есть несколько файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К которым я обращаюсь

```
Properties.strings.(строка)
```

Как получить *Properties.strings.(строка)* указав string ключ?

Тоесть если у меня есть там например строка English, то введя GetLocalizationString("English") чтобы я получил Properties.strings.English если он есть

Comment: Так сделайте перечисление (enum) доступных языков и в метод GetLocalizationString передавайте нужный язык, где будет swith-case или if\else if\else в зависимости от языка

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом `GetString` класса `ResouceManager`, передав ему первым параметром ключ строки, а вторым параметром необходимую культуру:

```
var ruCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
var ruString = Properties.strings.ResourceManager.GetString("someString", ruCulture); // strings.ru-RU.resx
```

Если вызвать GetString с одним аргументом, тогда строка будет взята из ресурса той культуры, которая указана текущей в  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`

```
var someString = Properties.strings.ResourceManager.GetString("someString"); // strings.resx
```

Если строка не найдена для той культуры, которую вы указываете, то она будет взята из ресурса по-умолчанию (resx без расширения языка)